# Running a java program which requires inputs on a webapp

Tags: java, html, heroku

I have a basic Java program that will run and take inputs in the console while outputting messages.

- How can I make it operate the same way on my webapp?

Currently I am trying this in my Java code...

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.applet.*;
 import java.awt.*;


 public class Game extends Applet{

 ...functions...

  public static void main(String args[]) {

  ...receiving inputs with scanner and outputting with System.out... 

  }
 }
```

and this in the body of my html...

```
 <APPLET CODE = "Game.class"  WIDTH = "800" HEIGHT = "500"></APPLET>
```

This displays a blank white square on the page with no functionality.

Comment: <APPLET codebase="classes"  CODE = "Game.class"  WIDTH = "800" HEIGHT = "500"></APPLET>
try this

Comment: On a sidenote: I would highly recommend you to look into other web technologies as Applets are not supported anymore anywhere and basically considered *dead*

Comment: <APPLET codebase="classes" CODE = "Game.class" WIDTH = "800" HEIGHT = "500"></APPLET> gives an error "ClassNotFoundException" Game.class         - Seems I have a different problem then